# Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBNull

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the C# and this function gives following error when I fetch data about an year

Code :var remainingItems = await search.GetRemainingAsync();

Exception : Unable to convert [Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBNull] of type Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBNull to System.String

Comment: Can you provide a little more code here? What is the "search" object? What does the 'GetRemainingAsync" method do?

Comment: GetRemainingAsync initiates the asynchronous execution to get all the remaining results form DynamoDB

Comment: Heya :) Were you able to resolve this in the end? Am troubled by the same issues

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem using PartiLQ, using the statement:

```
"UPDATE TABLE SET MyLongAttribute=null where PartitionKey=?";
```

The update was executed successfully, but the error occurs when I then tried to load the model back from the document record. The SDK complaints that `Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.DynamoDBNull` cannot be mapped into a `<nullable>long`.

This is related to a known problem https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/629

To resolve this problem, instead of setting the attribute to `null`, you should just remove the attribute from the object instead, e.g.

```
"UPDATE TABLE REMOVE MyLongAttribute where PartitionKey=?";
```

If you use the PutItem API instead of PartiLQ, and the attribute is a String instead of a long, the concept should still be similar. The GitHub reference above describes that the workaround is simple enough, AWS would not bother fixing this on the DotNet SDK.